# Run node app with SSL on 443 port (on 80 is working)

Tags: node.js, linux, apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

It's my first time when I try configure a server running on Amazon EC2.

I figured out how run my node app on 80 port but now I'm trying to run on 443 port with Letsencrypt SSL. Before to work on 80 port I added

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

and

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

and everything worked fine. But now after install Letsencrypt I try to do same thing but with 433 port instead 80 and it's not working.

Letsencrypt config automatically for me all files so now redirect from http to https is working fine and when my iptable is empty on https:// I see ubuntu default website. When I run lines mentioned above with 443 port app is still not working (browser can't even load anything). It's only working with http:/...:3000

I've added 443 port to Security Groups on EC2.

What I can do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your security group Inbound/Outbound rules, you need to see if port 443 is assigned to which host. A valid but dangerous configuration, just for testing, is allow everything on Inbound and Outbound, to see if its a problem on your Security Group.

Beyond that, you need to be sure if the binding port is listening. Are you using Amazon Linux?

Comment: In inbound I've got 443 port set to 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0. In outbound "all trafic" set to 0.0.0.0/0. After a few hours I see that when I set port 443 redirect to 3000 with lines mentioned in first post, https:... shows me ubuntu default website. I'm using Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Interesting. So, your Inbound/Outbound rules are fine, no problem there. Lets see if I got this right, you want to access your server by port 443, it doesn't work, but you can access through 3000?

Comment: Yes, it's working when I access it like http:/... :3000

Comment: Try this: sudo ufw allow 443/tcp - Its a alternative from iptables, see it if works.